# Laravel : Call to a member function index() on null

Tags: php, css, html, laravel

When I created model in laravel after that i migrate table through php artisan migrate it shows error on terminal:
Call to a member function index() on null

Comment: plese can you provide whole error code?

Comment: What were you trying to do ? Which page or controller method you tried to load ?

Comment: $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable->index();

Answer (score 1):

It should be nullable()

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();

Or

$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();
```

After changing migration code, drop the tables and re-run migration. It should work.

Comment: thanks for your help